# Bitcoind in test network doesn't display transactions

Tags: transactions, testnet, faucets

Hello i'm setting up the bitcoin-core daemon, i use version `160300` ( but it is same problem with newer version ).

I have made config like this:

`testnet.conf`

```
server=1
listen=50
listenonion=0
testnet=1
bind=127.0.0.1:18333
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
rpcuser=bob
rpcpassword=12345
rpcport=18332
port=18333

datadir=/home/testnet/
pid=/home/testnet/.pid
```

then i run `bitcoind`:

`bitcoind -daemon -conf="~/btc/testnet.conf"`

Now i got me some address, using:
`bitcoin-cli --rpcuser="bob" --rpcpassword="12345" --rpcport=18332 getnewaddress "test_user"`

Result is `2NF9YinW7mqpUGy1GySD2xEV11uVPbQggbb`

Then i go to this site `https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet/`

I enter this address `2NF9YinW7mqpUGy1GySD2xEV11uVPbQggbb` and press send, it gives me back transaction id, this is it here https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/d2aa744b33e60f959217cf2ae3852f8826bb2d977839b4a2be0a958aec6a9984/

But i do now:

```
bitcoin-cli --rpcuser="bob" --rpcpassword="12345" --rpcport=18332 listtransactions
```

and in result get this:

```
[
]
```

No incoming transactions. `getbalance` returns 0

Can someone help. what is going on, do i need to mine blocks or something to get that transaction ? Or should i wait more for bitcoind to work ?

**UPDATE:**

The output of `getblockcount` is `1381543` and it seems to increase when i send `getblockcount` again

The output of `getblockchaininfo` is:

```
{
  "chain": "test",
  "blocks": 1381659,
  "headers": 1580289,
  "bestblockhash": "0000000000000095a7c30336ab1c9f12260b5a8fb2deb6dde59ab8c372376a64",
  "difficulty": 17349304.92883517,
  "mediantime": 1533662288,
  "verificationprogress": 0.8876421741980308,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008b05062dc0c9f9c122",
  "size_on_disk": 15923153327,
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": [
    {
      "id": "bip34",
      "version": 2,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip66",
      "version": 3,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bip65",
      "version": 4,
      "reject": {
        "status": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "bip9_softforks": {
    "csv": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1456790400,
      "timeout": 1493596800,
      "since": 770112
    },
    "segwit": {
      "status": "active",
      "startTime": 1462060800,
      "timeout": 1493596800,
      "since": 834624
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```

Comment: Is Bitcoin Core synced yet? What do you get for `getblockcount`? Can you update your question with the output of `getblockchaininfo`?

Comment: @AndrewChow i have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin Core has not yet fully synced the testnet blockchain. You can see this in the `getblockchaininfo` output, it has `"initialblockdownload": true` and the number of blocks is less than the number of headers (headers are synced first so the number of headers indicates the number of blocks that need to be synced).

You should see your balance once your node has fully synced.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you did not give bitcoind time to "sync", no other explanation comes to mind. Starting bitcoin-qt may be more obvious.